# Result not evaluated

Tags: output

When I type:

```
QuantityMagnitude[3.4 m]
```

I got only the same sentence as a result. I am expecting `3.4`

Trying to figure out what is not working, `N[Sqrt[2]]` produced, as expected:  `1.41421`.
What might be wrong here?

Comment: You probably didn't type the unit correctly. See here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html

Comment: I had seen that, but m was also mentioned here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantityMagnitude.html , but it did not work for me. I got it now working typing "earth gravity" in free-from and then QuantityMagnitude[%].

Comment: Did you type the unit as described in the reference page I linked? Or did you literally type `3.4 m`?

Comment: You linked to `Quantity` but we are talking about `QuantityMagnitude` (which I had linked to in my later comment). this are different.

Comment: You did not answer my question. I linked to the reference page describing how to enter units.

Comment: All evidence so far indicates that you simply typed the unit incorrectly (neither with Ctrl-= nor with an explicit `Quantity` and a valid unit name). Voting to close as simple mistake. If my assumption is incorrect, please describe the problem in more detail, and indicate how you entered the unit precisely.

Comment: The input to `QuantityMagnitude` must be a `Quantity`. Copy and paste the example from the documentation, then convert it to `InputForm` you will see 

`QuantityMagnitude[Quantity[3.4, 
     "Meters"]]`

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon , But this is  very ambiguous from the documentation, unless this followed a rule of which I am not aware. It seams this is a way to implicitly include something and just link to it. Thanks.